# Geometric Progression prove question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that a, b, c and d are in geometric progression prove that:

$(b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 + (d-b)^2 = (a-d)^2$

I've established that ar = b, br = c, cr = d where r is a common ratio.

However I do not understand what my next approach should be.

Thanks

I've done this, thus far:

$(ar-ar^2)^2+(ar^2-a)^2+(ar^3-ar)^2$

Sort of unrelated to this, but is there a quick way to expand expressions like these?

I found this:
$a^2r^6-2a^2r^3+a^2$

But how can I divide by $a^2$ if this an expression and not an equation?

Comment: Try expressing everything in terms of $a,r$. Substitute. Cancel out $a$. Square and establish an identity with what remains.

Comment: Hint 2: The equation you have needs to be simplified (expressed in terms of only two variables, say $a, r$. Use $b  = ar, c = ar^2, ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $b = ar$, $c=ar^2$ and $d=ar^3$.

Then the left side of your equation is

\begin{align}
&(ar-ar^2)^2 + (ar^2-a)^2 + (ar^3-ar)^2 \\
&= a^2r^2(1-r)^2+a^2(r^2-1)^2+a^2r^2(r^2-1)^2\\ 
&= a^2(1-r)^2(r^2+(r+1)^2+r^2(r+1)^2)\\
&=a^2(1-r)^2(r^2+r+1)^2\\ 
&=(a(1-r^3))^2=(a-d)^2\end{align}

Comment: did you factor $a^2$? I factor $a^2$ and get $a^2(r^2(1-r)^2+(r^2-1)^2+r^2(r^2-1)^2)$

Comment: @user90771 Yes. In the third line, I factored $a^2$ and also a $(1-r)^2$.

Comment: How can you factor the $(1-r)^2$? How does $\frac{a^2(r^2-1)^2}{a^2(1-r)^2} = (r+1)^2$

Comment: @user90771 Yes. Use $r^2-1 = (r-1)(r+1)$ to see this.

Comment: sorry I still didn't understand. 

$\frac{((r-1)(r+1))^2}{(1-r)^2}$ = ? (how does this simplify into $(r+1)^2$?

Is $(r-1) = (1-r)$? If so how/why?

Comment: @user90771 $(r^2-1)^2 = ((r-1)(r+1))^2=(r-1)^2(r+1)^2=(1-r)^2(r+1)^2$.

Comment: oh ok, I understand now. So $(r-1)^2=(1-r)^2$, is there an intuitive reasoning behind why this is true?

Comment: @user90771 $(r-1)$ is the negative of $(1-r)$, so the square of them is the same non-negative quantity (just like $(-3)^2=3^2$). Algebraically, $(r-1)^2=((-1)(1-r))^2=(-1)^2(1-r)^2=(1-r)^2$.

Comment: lastly, once you got $(a(1-r^3))^2$, how does this equal $(a-d)^2$?

Comment: @user90771 $(1-r)(1+r+r^2) = (1-r^3)$. In general, $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x^3-y^3)$. This is a well-know identity. You can verify this by expanding.

Comment: @user90771 Please avoid editing your comments to ask a completely different question. I'm not notified of any edits you make for me to respond and this also makes my responses to your original question baseless. As for your question, $a(1-r^3)=(a-ar^3)=(a-d)$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, we need to eliminate $b,c$ from the left hand side

Assuimng $a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\ne0,$

$$\text{ As }\frac ba=\frac cb=\frac dc,\text{  we have } b^2=ca,c^2=bd, ad=bc$$

$$(b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 + (d-b)^2 $$

$$= b^2+c^2-2bc+c^2+a^2-2ca+d^2-2bd+b^2$$

$$=a^2+d^2+2(b^2+c^2-bc-ca-bd)$$

$$=a^2+d^2+2(ca+bd-ad-ca-bd)$$

$$=a^2+d^2-2ad=(a-d)^2$$

Comment: fantastic method thanks

Comment: @user90771, my pleasure. Sometimes looking at the Right Hand side helps optimizing the answer